# running apps on WiFi with proxy or alternate to ad-hoc network between laptop and phone?

Tags: wi-fi, 2.3-gingerbread, proxy, ad-hoc-networks

My home WiFi runs behind a proxy.

When I connect to it from my Samsung Galaxy S with android 2.3.3, after entering the proxy and port number in the settings, I am able to run only the browser(not any apps). After searching on Google, I found out that the apps can be run behind proxy only if I root the phone. But rooting the phone would void its warranty. I don't want that to happen.

Instead I connected to LAN from my laptop and created a Ad-hoc network. I thought that if I connect to this network from my phone, I won't have to worry about proxy. Am I right ?

Now my phone was not able to discover this Ad-hoc connection. Again after Googling, I found that it is not possible to connect to ad-hoc without rooting the phone. Is there any other method than creating ad-hoc network to share the internet from my laptop to my phone?

Is there any way to run apps on my phone connected to my home WIFi without rooting my phone ?